# Magento 2: Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View Block

Tags: magento2

I have developed one custom module and i have tried to override product view block by following these two links [Overriding Block in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76590/overriding-block-in-magento-2)
and [DI & Extending a Block on Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74632/di-extending-a-block-on-magento-2) but when i hit product view page its gives me 404 page. what i have done so far is below

**di.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct"/>
   </config>
```

**Myproduct.php**

```
<?php
namespace TT\Helloworld\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
class Myproduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{

protected $_helper;

protected $_objectManager;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        array $data = [],
        \TT\Helloworld\Helper\Data $helper  
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data,$helper);

    $this->_helper = $helper;

}

protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

As per [DI & Extending a Block on Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74632/di-extending-a-block-on-magento-2) link i have also included all the parent class construct parameter in Myproduct.php constructer.

anyone one know where i'm wrong? or what is the correct way to override this?

Comment: you will find your solution follow the link. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2/86655#86655

Comment: @AnandOntigeri that solution also not working can you add solution here?

Comment: `TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct.php` ==> `TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct` (remove `.php`)

Comment: @BriceC.that also not working

Comment: No errors in log? try to comment your `__construct`

Comment: @Brice main.CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\var\generation\TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\code\TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct.php on line 13 [] []

Comment: remove `C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\var\generation\TT\Helloworld\Block\Myproduct\Intercepto‌​r.php` and comment the `__construct` method and try again please

Comment: @Brice thanks, error removed but without __construct magento 2 won't able to find my custom html file and giving error like main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'myproduct.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'tt_helloworld.myproduct' [] [.  My template file is located at view/frontend/templates/myproduct.phtml

Comment: good explanation @Brice

Comment: You can check controller, model and helper override here http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/overriding-controller-block-model-and-helper-in-magento-2-using-preference/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resume

- comment `__construct` method (temporary solution)
- remove `Interceptor` generated (new one will be generated - need to be removed after each modification of `__construct` method)
- in your layout use `template="TT_Helloworld::myproduct.phtml"`

Comment: i don't understand what is the reason behind remove __construct method from my class?

Comment: it was for debug, you can now try to uncomment the method.

Answer (score 2):

you need to enter \TT\Helloworld\Helper\Data $helper before array $data = [] in the __contruct

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \TT\Helloworld\Helper\Data $helper ,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data,$helper);
```