# Magento 2 overriding Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, meta, override-block

I have made a module to override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View. I want to add some standard things to the MetaTitle and MetaDescription on the product page. Specifically for empty descriptions.

**Alters**

I alter the title string and save with

`$this->pageConfig->setTitle($myString)`.

The same goes for the description

```
$this->pageConfig->setDescription($myOtherString)
```

**Problem**

The MetaTitle and MetaDescription on the product page stay the same.

**Possible causes and solutions**

I have investigated and ruled out the following:

- Cache
- Third party modules
- Module related problems (magento setup:upgrade,...)

**Debug**

When I echo the string I want to set I get the following error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:282:"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /app/code/[MyVendor]/[MyModule]/Block/Product/View.php:61) in /www/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 125";i:1;s:1702:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '/data/sites/web...', 125, Array)
#1 /www/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(125): setcookie('mage-messages', '[]', 1533729078, '/', '', false, false)
#2 /www/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(98): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('mage-messages', '[]', Array)
#3 /www/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(85): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setPublicCookie('mage-messages', '[]', Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata))
#4 /www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(152): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor))
#5 /www/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#6 /www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#8 /www/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

But I think this is more an issue of the echo than error due to code error.

I mainly followed [this logic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95697/magento-2-override-magento-catalog-block-product-view-block). Is there another logic I should follow or does anyone have an idea of why the metainfo does not change?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You cant override View.php file you have to create plugin for your changes.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Is it possible to get a specific example of a plugin for metadata?

Comment: I've studied Plugins but are too limiting for my purposes. eg. I want to be able to call the current product. Plugins don't seem suitable to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml
```

create di.xml file and called plugin function,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
        <plugin name="block_product_view_plugin" type="Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Productview"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Create plugin file inside your module,**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Plugin;

use Closure;

class Productview
{
    public function aroundGetProduct( 
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $subject,
        Closure $proceed
    )
    {       
        $newdata = $proceed();        

        if($newdata){
            $metaTitle = $newdata->getMetaTitle(); 
            $newdata->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);           
            return $newdata; 
        }
        return $newdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this acts on the product itself. I want to change the metadescription according to the product page. It would be nice to include the current category in the metadescription