# Inject class for overridded class

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalog, dependency-injection

I override the `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` it's working but I am trying to inject class means it's not working please tell me what I did wrong and tell me how to do this without injecting the core class

```
    <?php
    namespace Eventbefore\Block\Product;

    use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

    class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View{

        protected $logger;

        protected $objectManager;

        protected $_curl;

        public function __construct(
            CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
            CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
            SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager, 
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl)
        {
            $this->_curl = $curl;
            $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
            $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
            $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
            $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
             //parent::__construct($context);
        }
}
```

Error:

> Eventbefore\Block\Product\View
>
> ```
>       Missed required argument urlEncoder in parent::__construct call. File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/rumin/app/code/Cart/Eventbefore/Block/Product/View.php
> ```

Answer (score 0):

According to this question
[Magento 2: Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View Block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95697/magento-2-override-magento-catalog-block-product-view-block)

and to the exception you have, I guess you have to add this to the construct method and pass it to the parent cuonstructor

```
public function __construct(
        .......
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder, 
) {
    parent::__construct(...., $urlEncoder, ...);

}
```

Comment: Is that necessary to inject that class, those classes already in core files right?

Comment: According to your exception you have to inject it... or uncomment parent cunstroctor

Comment: I have uncommented and tried it's coming like this, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function registry() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php:172 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/rumin/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php(128): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View->getProduct()