# Magento 2.3.1 media urls in custom attribute of text editor type displaying as text

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes, magento2.3.1, media

I've created a product attribute to display content in the product tabs which is specifically for technical drawings. The attribute is set as text editor type.

When I add an image using the "insert image" button the code is correct, as follows:

```
<img src="{{media url="diagrams/MCP-Typical-Wiring.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

However, this doesn't display on the frontend, it is outputting as text:

```
<img src="{{media url=" diagrams="" mcp-typical-wiring.jpg"}}"="" alt="">
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: I have faced the same issue in my magento 2.3.1 project and  i have resolved this issue the method I mentioned below

Comment: Thanks - can you help with where I should add this code please? I have used the block class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View in my catalog_product_view.xml file and linked this to a new .phtml file which calls the new attribute I created.

Comment: You can override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View in your custom module and pass that attribute value to a custom function from the template file.  Refer
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95697/magento-2-override-magento-catalog-block-product-view-block. Or its feel difficult for you, your can try object manager. Using object manager in the template file is not a good practice

Answer (score 3):

You need to filter that editor content using cms page filter. in your block class

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider)
    {
      $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;                       
     }
```

Now use `$this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where would I add this code?

Answer (score 0):

You try to filter in details.phtml

> Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterProvider = $objectManager->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider');
$html = $filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($html);
```