# Block override in Magento2 not working

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, dependency-injection

I'm working on a custom module for magento2. Trying to override the product view block so I can fetch data from an API and pass it into the view. Having read

1. https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Overriding-a-block-in-Magento-2/m-p/6831#U6831
2. [Magento 2: Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View Block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95697/magento-2-override-magento-catalog-block-product-view-block)
3. [DI & Extending a Block on Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74632/di-extending-a-block-on-magento-2)

I'm still unsuccessful... Here's what I have in my module (Moxune/Moxune):

Block/Product/View.php

```
<?php
namespace Moxune\Moxune\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Moxune\Moxune\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

I then run

```
rm -rf var/cache var/di var/generation var/page_cache && ./bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and navigate to a product detail page. I can tell the overridden block isn't getting called though, because I've changed the `_toHtml()` body to:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
   die('wtf');
}
```

and also introduced syntax errors and the page continues to load fine. However, if I put a `die` statement in the `_toHtml()` of

var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php

that shows on the product detail page. So it seems the preference I'm configuring is having no effect?

FWIW - It seems the DI process is creating a new Interceptor based on the configured preference:

var/generation/Moxune/Moxune/Block/Product/View/Interceptor.php

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you get when you call `get_class($block);` in your product view template ?

Comment: Which template file should I be looking at, seems like there's several. I'm looking in the `./vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view` directory. Added a `get_class($block)` in the `details.phtml` file and get `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description`

Comment: try the `view/frontend/templates/product/view.phtml`

Comment: Haven't tracked it down yet, but feels like something isn't right w/ the DI generation process. The preferences configuration has _Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View_ => _Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor_ for some reason.

Comment: I don't have a `view.phtml` file, all that's in the `view/frontend/templates/product` directory is `compare  gallery.phtml  image.phtml  image_with_borders.phtml  list  listing.phtml  list.phtml  view  widget`, inside the `view` directory are `additional.phtml  addto.phtml      attributes.phtml   details.phtml  gallery.phtml  opengraph  options.phtml      review.phtml
addtocart.phtml   attribute.phtml  description.phtml  form.phtml     mailto.phtml   options    price_clone.phtml  type`

Answer (score 2):

So I got *something* working... I discovered the DI configuration was mapping `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` to `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor` which is not the generated interceptor I was expecting (`Moxune\Moxune\Block\Product\View\Interceptor`).

I'm not sure exactly why, but my Magento installation (v2.0.4) does not have a `view/frontend/templates/product/view.phtml` file, so my guess is the block I was trying to override isn't being used. I did find several other (seemingly more granular) template files and decided to shoot for a block that might correspond to one of those.

That said, I've

1. Changed my module's `di.xml` file to

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"
           type="Moxune\Moxune\Block\Product\View\Description" />
   </config>
   ```
2. Created the corresponding class

   ```
   namespace  Moxune\Moxune\Block\Product\View;

   use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
   use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
   use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

   class Description extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description {
       protected function _toHtml() {   
           $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description'));
           return parent::_toHtml();
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Recompiled the DI configuration

   ```
   rm -rf var/cache var/di var/generation var/page_cache ; ./bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```

Now I seem to be getting into the `_toHtml` method of my overridden class!